Tax description is not displayed on sales-order-view page in My orders

How ever its working fine in invoice tab.

If someone faced this issue or have any solution please suggest.

Seems like, There is something causing an issue with your theme customization.
Please apply luma theme, and check it it is getting displayed, It means there is block missing in the order total.
You can add wee_tax inside the below block which renders the order total in sales_order_view.
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Weee\Block\Sales\Order\Totals" name="weee_ord_totals">
        <action method="setBeforeCondition">
            <argument name="condition" xsi:type="string">tax</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</block>


I have added this block inside the order totals, it is rendering now. Thanks!
